# Cross Validation - Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

I want to make a logistic regression with N independent variables, via cross validation (K splits). I want to use the resulting betas in order to put it in a formula to predict future cases (no yet in my data).

Provided K splits, I would get K sets of resulting $?\beta$s, so... the 'final' betas are the average of each $\beta_i$? Because it is clear the average error should be obtained from the average of results, but it is not so clear the average $\beta$s would correspond to the average error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there might be some confusion here...

Cross-validation lets you choose from a family of models by estimating the prediction error for each one of them. One then takes the model whose estimated error is minimal.

Say you have a family of models $f_\alpha$ indexed by a hyperparameter $\alpha$. Cross-validation provides a function $CV(\hat{f},\alpha)$, where $\hat{f}$ denotes the models trained with CV, for fixed $\alpha$. You then pick $\hat{\alpha} \in \operatorname{argmin} CV(\hat{f},\alpha)$ and retrain the model $f_\alpha$ with all the data. This gives you $\hat{f}_\alpha$ with some specific set of parameters.

In logistic regression these parameters are your betas, and the hyperparameter $\alpha$ is the regularization coefficient for standard Tykhonov regularization, and it is typically $C$ or $\lambda$, ($C=1 / \lambda$).

For a good explanation of model selection see Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman ["The Elements of statistical learning"](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf), Chapter 7.

Comment: I kinda disagree with your definition of CV. CV aims at assessing how the results of a model will generalize to an independent dataset. The same statistical analysis (same model, same (hyper)parameters) is applied sequentially to different subsets of a dataset (with numerous variations on how-to). You seem to be saying CV is applied across a series of models. Apologies in case I misunderstood your reply,

Comment: Yes, I meant what you say. By estimating how different models will generalise, one can choose among them. CV is performed for each of them in turn. For the case of logistic regression see e.g. [what sklearn does](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegressionCV.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the procedure I looked for here https://mingchen0919.github.io/learning-apache-spark/k-folds-cross-validation.html

Comment: That link details the procedure I described (not that I'm claiming any merit for CV!). They use two hyperparameters though: a penalty coefficient and the $p$ for the $p$-norm.

Comment: Also, if you don't accept my answer, you could post your comment as one, with some explanation as to what is being described in that site and accept it, for future users. It seems like CV for logistic regression is a common question here.

Comment: Miguel that is not the intention of CV, so I agree with tagoma.  If you are going to use CV to choose a model you need to have an additional validation loop around the whole process.  But note that for adequate precision you often have to repeat 10-fold CV 50-100 times even when you don't need the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks all Miguel, Frank etc. In the following link I found (https://mingchen0919.github.io/learning-apache-spark/k-folds-cross-validation.html) I found the kind of algorithm I was looking for, where it is mentioned the procedure I should follow in order to select the resulting betas after having passed through all the folds and then being tested with the test set (which was taken before the k folds, which was one misunderstanding from my side). Ciao

Comment: @FrankHarrell Then there is clearly something I do not understand. Maybe it is a matter of nomenclature? By family of models I mean some hypothesis space indexed by hyperparameters. Take e.g. §5.3 of Wasserman's "All of nonparametric statistics": CV is used to estimate the risk for a nonparametric estimator and minimise that to select the best bandwidth. Or §7.10 of Hastie's ESL, which is were I learnt about CV and my answer basically copies. I'd be grateful for some clarification!

Comment: Those are examples where an outer loop is needed because you can be over optimistic when allowing optimization of a global performance measure.

Comment: @FrankHarrell While trying to understand what you meant with outer loops, I came upon [Cawley2010](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf) which if I'm not mistaken, basically states that, regardless of the unbiasedness of the (leave-one-out) CV estimator, its variance can be high so optimising the hyperparameters using it as a risk estimator can result in overfitting to the finite sample that one has (§4 of the paper). The smaller the dataset, the worse the effect of course. (continues below...)

Comment: So this means that the references I gave do not paint the whole picture and direct optimisation of the CV score can yield bogus results. I see that now, thanks! However, I don't see what's the use of an estimator of the risk if not used to select models. Note also, that the link provided by the OP, as well as the references I gave, all use CV for this purpose, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Often model selection works less well than full model pre-specification.